# Daniel/Pryce -- how would he have found the veterinarian?

Tags: better-call-saul

The vet is normally how Mike finds work but how would "Pryce" even establish credibility with the vet so that he would refer Mike and the other two men (one of whom was referred to Saul by the vet)? That might be the hard part, the vet probably not wanting to have nothing to do with such a novice; but the other thing, even finding out about the vet seems pretty unlikely also. In fact, the tall guy whom Mike beat up seems sort of flakey although maybe that implies that the vet is less careful than one might think.

I could see Pryce knowing the vet socially and just telling him that he wants to perform a cash transaction of some sort and that he needs security as being how the initial meeting with Mike and the two others occurred. Perhaps the vet would have handled everything, not allowing Pryce to contact the security guys directly.

But maybe such details are explained in the show and I missed them?

Comment: The "tall guy who Mike beat up" is actually pretty competent. Saul and Kim use him to try to dig dirt on Kevin. He takes pains to demonstrate that he's proficient in what he does.

Comment: I think the tall guy is not competent -- while he broke into the banker's office and got info, he is also a loose cannon who suggested torturing the banker to get further info. That he carried so many guns for the Nacho meeting is also showing that he lacks a sense of proportion; that he gets beaten up even before this fairly routine meeting (in their world) is more evidence.

Comment: As far as people in that line of work goes, he is sufficiently competent to get the job done. That doesn't mean he is as competent as Mike, or that he is a good person.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Wormald was probably put in touch with the vet through word of mouth. The vet was very well known in Albuquerque's underground. All Daniel needed was to have his name passed along. It's not outside of the realms of possibility that Daniel already knew someone who had some shady connections. Alternatively, it wouldn't be too hard for a complete novice like him to get in touch with someone who did have those connections.

He had $20k worth of medicine that was of interest to criminals. Someone would take note of a amateur trying to get sell that sort of product.

The vet's own "vetting" process was probably sufficient for their needs. Criminals are not often the most accomplished of people, but there's a difference between being the "very best person for a job" or "sufficiently skilled to do what they've been asked to do." Could Sobchak have guarded Daniel sufficiently to handle the medicine exchange? Probably. Was he more likely than Mike to do something stupid and start a fire-fight, getting someone killed or arrested? Absolutely.

That doesn't mean that the vet didn't do his due diligence in selecting Sobchak for that job, just that as far as criminals willing to babysit a nerd through a high value drug deal are generally not the exemplars of skill that Mike Ehrmantraut is.